# Why is Nginx routing all traffic to one subdomain?

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx. I am trying to install GitLabs alongside an existing php project which is currently being served by Apache on port 80. My plan is to get them both working side by side on port 90 and then turn off Apache, switching both projects to Nginx on port 80.

Okay. The problem is that both subdomains are being captured by the `server` for my php project which should only be served to requests for `db.mydomain.com`. For the php project I have a file called: `ccdb` symlinked into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. It contains:

```
server {
    server_name db.mydomain.com;
    listen  90; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/ccdb;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

However, for some reason, traffic to git.mydomain.com is being serverd from `/var/www/ccdb` even though I have another file symlinked alongside that one called `gitlab` with this content:

```
# GITLAB
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 5.0

upstream gitlab {
    server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
    listen 90;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
    server_name git.mydomain.com;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
    server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
    root /home/git/gitlab/public;

    # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

    location / {
        # serve static files from defined root folder;.
        # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
    }

    # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
    # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
    location @gitlab {
        proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am accessing the two domains from an OSX machine on the same local network which has entries in it's `/etc/hosts` file like so:

```
192.168.1.100 db.mydomain.com
192.168.1.100 git.mydomain.com
```

Comment: the simple explanation is that the request doesn't match any `server_name` so it goes to the first server unless there's one defined as `default_server`

Comment: does `http://git.mydomain.com:90` work correctly ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Looks like you are correct. For some reason neither `server_name` is matching so it just picks the first server alphabetically. Any idea how I can tell what `server_name` nginx seeing?

Comment: well not really, but I would like if you tried `sudo nginx -t`

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok //
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
server_name git.mydomain.com:90;
```

... and:

```
server_name db.mydomain.com:90;
```